# Latest version of Xcode isn't compatible with Mountain Lion

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I upgraded to Mac OS 10.8 (Mountain Lion), and I'm having a problem installing Xcode 4.3.1 from the Mac App Store. It says:

```
"Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because the version of OS X is too new."
```

Any ideas folks ? Thanks in advance.

im enrolled in iOS developer program not Mac program ,thanks

EDIT

im an iOS developer and i want to download iOS SDK for developing apps on iPhone, iPod and iPad .not a Mac/Safari developer and i made i quick search and discovered that apple didn't release a version of xcode "developing for iOS "that's compatible with mountain lion "installable on mountain lion not developing for mountain lion!",i have to set and wait for week or two,thanks

Comment: The Mountain Lion Developer Preview is under NDA, and surely there exists documentation from Apple on the correct version of Xcode to use with it.

Comment: It's called Developer Preview for a reason … You can get Xcode 4.4 which is compatible with ML through Apples Developer Connection ;)

Comment: im enrolled in iOS developer program not Mac program ,thanks

Comment: So ask the guy, who violated his NDA to do so again.

Comment: If you continue to get this error after the release of Mountain Lion: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57518/why-cant-i-install-xcode-4-4-on-mountain-lion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the version of Xcode available from the member center (Xcode 4.4) specifically designed for Mountain Lion!

You can [download XCode](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) if you are enrolled to the iOS **or** Mac Developer Program

Comment: im enrolled in iOS developer program not Mac developer program.

Comment: if you are not in the Mac Developer Program you shouldn't have access to mountain lion in the first place.

Comment: Matthias is right - you must be in the Mac Developer Program to have access to Mountain Lion!

Comment: im an iOS developer and i want to download iOS SDK for developing apps on iPhone, iPod and iPad .not a Mac/Safari developer and i made i quick search and discovered that apple didn't release a version of xcode "dev. for iOS "that's compatible with mountain lion "installable on mountain lion not developing for mountain lion!",i have to set and wait for week or two,thanks

Comment: The 4.4 dev preview supports iOS, but as you need to be a Mac developer to get ML, you need to be a Mac developer to get 4.4 preview. Either go back to Lion or find a way to get 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a special version of XCode for your MAC OS X Mountain Lion  on Apple website : 
[XCode 4.4 Mountain Lion Developer Preview](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php)